# Return value from stored procedure called inside another stored procedure in snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call a stored procedure inside another stored procedure  in Snowflake using SQL Language:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Parent_Proc(process_tbl varchar ,audit_tbl varchar,process_nm array)       
returns varchar
as  
declare
  COUNTER int default 1;
  tmp varchar;
begin
  while (COUNTER <= ARRAY_SIZE(process_nm) ) do
    tmp := process_nm[COUNTER-1] ;
    call Child_Proc( :process_tbl ,:audit_tbl, :tmp );
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
    -- return 'ABC'
   end while;
end;
```

Here wanted to return value of each Child_Proc call.

```
For example:
process_nm + 'return value of Child_Proc1-Failed/Succeeded'
process_nm + 'return value of Child_Proc2-Failed/Succeeded'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to return multiple rows as table from a stored procedure by using `RESULTSET`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CA_DCRT_PRODUCT_ANALYTICS.DRI_DERA_DEV.WRAPPER_MAIN_SP(
           process_table_name varchar ,audit_table_name varchar,process_name array)
returns table(result TEXT)  -- <<< 
LANGUAGE SQL 
as 
$$ 
declare
   COUNTER int := 1;
   tmp varchar;
   result varchar;
   res RESULTSET;  -- <<<
begin
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE Result_Entry(Result VARCHAR); -- <<<

  while (COUNTER <= ARRAY_SIZE(process_name)) do
     tmp := process_name[COUNTER-1] ;
     call CA_DCRT_PRODUCT_ANALYTICS.DRI_DERA_DEV.SNOWFLAKE_DATA_FLATTENING_PROC(
                        :process_table_name ,:audit_table_name,:tmp)
     INTO :result;
       
     INSERT INTO Result_Entry(Result) SELECT :result;   --<<<

     COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
     end while;
     
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Result FROM Result_Entry');  -- <<<

  RETURN TABLE(res);  -- <<<

end; 
$$;
```

Comment: I was wondering how to pass child_Proc as argument ?
`call :Child_Proc ( :process_table_name ,:audit_table_name,:tmp)`
Getting error for this..

Comment: @user13975334 This is out of scope of the initial question. Anyway to parametrize name you normally use `IDENTIFIER()` so `CALL IDENTIFIER(:child_proc_variable) (...)`

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable with type which is matching the one return by your internal stored procedure and assign the value like this:

```
CALL Child_Proc( :process_tbl ,:audit_tbl, :tmp ) INTO :result_variable;
```

Comment: Its working , but how to return value from each call of S.P, somehow it is returning only value of one call.
Child_Proc is called multiple times.

Comment: When the call is executed, you get the current result in your variable. You can just select it or insert it in a table and outside the loop to select from it.

Comment: I had created a temporary table outside loop..then inserting result inside loop.
then selecting result again outside the loop.
But it is not working for me.

Comment: What is not working exactly? You get an error or the table is empty?

Comment: //Creating local temp table outside loop
  `execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE Result_Entry(Result VARCHAR)';`

 //Inserting data into the local temp table inside loop
    ` execute immediate 'INSERT INTO Result_Entry(result)' ;`

//Selecting data outside loop
`execute immediate 'SELECT * FROM Result_Entry' ;`

Error : Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 14 at position 5 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 32 unexpected '<EOF>'.